# Implementing an interface with a generic parameter on a F# record

Tags: c#, .net, logging, f#

I'm trying to implement the an [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/ILogger.cs) (copied below for brevity) on a [F# Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records)

```cs
using System;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter);
        bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel);
        IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state);
    }
}
```

This is the record implementation.

```ml
  type ILoggerRcd<'TState> = 
    {
      BeginScope : 'TState -> IDisposable
      IsEnabled : LogLevel -> bool
      Log : LogLevel * EventId * 'TState * exn * Func<'TState,exn,string> -> unit
    }
    interface ILogger with
          override this.BeginScope(state : 'TState): IDisposable = 
              this.BeginScope (state)
          override this.IsEnabled(logLevel: LogLevel): bool = 
              this.IsEnabled logLevel
          override this.Log(logLevel: LogLevel, eventId: EventId, state : 'TState, ``exception``: exn, formatter: Func<'TState,exn,string>): unit = 
              this.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, ``exception``, formatter)
```

However, I'm getting this error on BeginScope: `One or more of the explicit class or function type variables for this binding could not be generalized, because they were constrained to other types`.

And this error on Log: `The generic member 'Log' has been used at a non-uniform instantiation prior to this program point. Consider reordering the members so this member occurs first. Alternatively, specify the full type of the member explicitly, including argument types, return type and any additional generic parameters and constraints.`

I've read through a few issues on fsharp compiler itself but nothing seems to be exactly this case I'm hitting. Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Have you tried making the field names in your record different to the member names of ILogger? Not sure if this would be confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to constrain `ILogger`'s `'TState` to match the `ILoggerRcd`'s `'TState`, but it's not your choice to do that.

To see this, note that a caller of `ILogger.BeginScope` can pass an `int` state on one call, and then a `string` state on another call **to the same `ILogger` instance**. Your implementation attempts to prevent this, hence the compiler errors.

The only way I can see around this is to use generic methods in your type instead of a record of functions. I don't think there's any way to do what you want using vanilla F# records.

Answer (score 3):

The `ILogger` interface requires that you can log objects of *any* type, but you're trying to log only those of type `'TState`.

Take the signature of `BeginScope`:

```
IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state);
```

See that `<TState>` bit there? That's a generic parameter. This signature means that every time anybody calls this method, they *get to choose a type `TState`* to use with that call.

Again: the *caller* chooses the generic type, not the implementer.

For example:

```
let l : ILogger = ...
l.BeginScope 42   // TState = int
l.BeginScope true // TState = bool
```

This means that your implementation of `BeginScope` has to be able to work with *any* type, not just the type with which your `ILoggerRcd` record was created.